# How do I create a pub package that works with Flutter?

Tags: dart-pub, flutter

pub is Dart's package manager. Flutter is a mobile app SDK that uses Dart. How can I create a package that depends on, or targets, Flutter?

Answer (score 4):

To declare a dependency on Flutter, from a pub package, add this to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

You must use `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`, because Flutter needs to set the appropriate environment variables to map the `sdk: flutter` to a location.

To easily and quickly create a new pub package, use the [stagehand](http://stagehand.pub) tool. After you install stagehand, follow these instructions:

```
$ mkdir fancy_project
$ cd fancy_project
$ stagehand package-simple
```

After you create your new package, edit the `pubspec.yaml` and add the `sdk:flutter` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

A trick I also use is to just `flutter create foo` (which creates a full-fledged Flutter app, more than you need) and then `rm -rf foo/ios foo/android` and edit/remove `foo/lib/main.dart`, etc.

The stagehand solution from @sethladd is more elegant, but requires having installed stagehand.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter create` now supports templates. 
The `package` template creates exactly that:

```
flutter create -t package
```

or to create a plugin that depends on platform-specific code:

```
flutter create -t plugin
```